# Ubuntu Studio 22.04 LTS: bluetooth speaker works once only.Trusted and paired but cannot conect.Cannot turn bluetooth off/on. Must reboot every time

Tags: sound, bluetooth, ubuntu-studio

Bluetooth is a standard, right? So if manufacturers and software devs follow the standard it should work. I cannot even understand how it is supposed to work.
I have Ubuntu Studio 22.04 LTS. Even When the bluetooth speaker is "paired" and "trusted" it works once and never again. "The device is not ready" message appears when I try to connect. Turning bluetooth off and on again from the panel has no effect. In the system settings bleutooth section it says "bluetooth is disabled" and the "enable" button has no effect whatsoever. I have tried systemctl in the terminal to start and stop bluetooth. It gives no error messages but does nothing. Usually The only way to get it to work is delete the device and start again, but even this requires a reboot to achieve. Sometimes a reboot is all that is required and it automatically connects when the bluetooth speaker is powered on, which is what it is supposed to do.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** I'd first confirm that you're running your BT service with `sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service`, and then run `bluetoothctl scan on` to see what BT devices are nearby. Then `bluetoothctl pair/connect` to watch for errors. And finally `bluetoothctl disconnect,`' again to watch for errors. Can you please edit your question to include these diagnostics? Thanks